# iPhone Break Point Problems with Two Types of Sliders - CSS

Tags: css

My boss wanted swipeable sliders for his website for mobile devices, and a slider with clickable buttons for desktop. I managed to implement a half-working solution, which singles out retina screens as having the swipeable version (the main target was iPhones). However, now every retina screen has the swipeable version, when retina desktops should have the clickable arrow slider.

I'm using CSS break points to hide and unhide two different sliders based on device. Is there any other way to specify my mobile slider just for iPhones and not desktops?

I'm looking for better break points that will ensure all phones get the swipeable slider and all desktops get the slider with buttons. Thanks for your help.

See an example of the slider: http://agentboris.com/home/index.php

Here is my CSS for breakpoints:

```
.displayphone{
    display: none;
    }

@media screen and (max-device-width:1081px)  {

.hidephone{
display: none
    }


.displayphone{
display: inline
    }

    }

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) 
{
    .hidephone{
display: none
    }


.displayphone{
display: inline
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use one slider that accepts both types of input?

Comment: That's true, I might go back to that. My boss said he wanted a different slider for desktop and mobile, because mobile generally always uses swipe  and not buttons, and vice versa for desktop.

Comment: Yeah, there's a few out there like this: http://ricostacruz.com/swipeshow/ which include swiping. It would be the better way to go since you'd probably have to re-do the breakpoints every time a new iPhone comes out. :)

Comment: Right, it's probably the best solution. Thanks for the reminder! I'll pass it along to my boss and see what he thinks. Cheers.